# what is the boundary and interior of $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x \text{ is rational}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the boundary and interior of $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x \text{ is rational}\}$?

Comment: Do you know what the boundary and interior of $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x\text{ is rational}\}$ is, and why? Your problem is closely related.

Comment: What do you mean by interior and boundary? Can you give a definition?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have asked for the boundary and the interior of a certain set.

Well, one of them is empty and the other is the whole $R^2$.

I let you decide which is which and why.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for interior points.

Set of all rational numbers are dense in reals. So every neighborhood of any point of the given set S having at least one  point which is not a member of given set S.
(i.e) A point having whose first coordinate as an irrational number.
Thus interior of the given set is **Empty set.**

Then, **Boundary** of the given set is R×R.

Because Every neibourhood of any point in R×R having at least one point from S and having at least one point from the complement of S.